# Flink Heap memory leaking?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink. My flink application (1.10.0) is run on k8s using hdfs. It seems like there are memory leaking issues because the heap memory always goes up when I check the heap memory usage. This will result in the app restart at some point. I tried to simplify my topology to only contain one Kafka consumer and one discard sink. But I still see it is using lots of memory. The max memory usaged in the picture below is about 60% which is 10 GB.

[image]

My `flink-conf.yaml` is like the following

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: streakerflink-jobmanager

high-availability: ZOOKEEPER
high-availability.cluster-id: /streaker
high-availability.storageDir: hdfs:///flink
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zookeeper.default.svc.k8s-westeros-master.local:2181
zookeeper.sasl.disable: true

taskmanager.network.bind-policy: ip

taskmanager.data.port: 6121
taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122

restart-strategy: fixed-delay
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 2147483647
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay: 5 s

taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size: 17g
taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size: 512m
taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 768m
taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 512m
taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max: 3g
taskmanager.memory.network.max: 3g
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size: 512m

metrics.internal.query-service.port: 6125
metrics.reporters: prom
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9999

web.log.path: /opt/flink/log/output.log
taskmanager.log.path: /opt/flink/log/output.log
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen any out of memory error within the log file? If so, kindly attach the log file. Could you enable the garbage collector log file and attach it? Thank you

Comment: Is there any logic at all between the Kafka source and the discarding sink?

Comment: No, there are not logic at all. I notice that every time it hit 50 percent of usages, the usages will drop. It will attempt three times. Then it will hit 75 percent and drop repeatedly. Eventually, it will run out of memories some time.